# Statistical test to compare global performance of two models over multiple data set of time series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have measurements from $N$ subjects. For each subjects $i \in {1,...,N}$, I measure three time series composed of $T_i$ elements : $x^i = \{x^i_1,...,x^i_{T_i}\}$, $y^i = \{y^i_1,...,y^i_{T_i}\}$ and $z^i = \{z^i_1,...,z^i_{T_i}\}$. I use two models to predict $z^i_t$ from $x^i_t$ and $y^i_t$ respectively, for $t \in {1,...,T_i}$. Using the corresponding residuals $r^i_{x_t}$ and $r^i_{y_t}$, I can test if the signal $x^i$ is better (provides the lowest errors) than $y^i$ to predict $z^i$ for a given subject $i$.

Now, I want to test statistically if the signals $x$ are generally better than $y$ to predict $z$. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know whether one model yields a statistically significant better prediction than the other, a paired t-test is appropriate. In R, this would be

```
zx <- predictionfrom(x)
zy <- predictionfrom(y)
t.test(zx, zy, paired=TRUE)
```

and then check whether the reported p-value is sufficiently small (e.g less than 0.01).

If you want to know which model is "better", you might also want to take into account the number of parameters in the model: a model with more parameters tends to yield better prediction results. Measures that try to quantize the trade-off between accuracy and the number of parameters are BIC or AIC.

Comment: Thank you. Both models have same number of parameters. Is it ok to use a paired t-test if each time series $x^i$ is correlated to $y^i$ (and having correlated residuals) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason why a *paired* test must be used: it assumes correlation between $x_i$ and $y_i$, but independece between $x_i - y_i$ and $x_k - y_k$ for $i\neq k$.